# How to provide something through DI (Koin) to a @BindingAdapter method?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-databinding, android-glide, koin

If this would be easier solved in some other way, I would be happy to hear it, but here it goes.

I want to provide my @BindingAdapter method with an instance of Glide in some way so that I can create it once. I am currently providing this with Koin here:

```
val glideModule = module {
    single { provideRequestOptions() }
    single { provideRequestManager(androidApplication(), get()) }
}

fun provideRequestManager(
    application: Application,
    requestOptions: RequestOptions
): RequestManager {
    return Glide.with(application)
        .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
}

fun provideRequestOptions(): RequestOptions {
    return RequestOptions()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_animation)
        .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image)
}
```

I have a @BindingAdapter method that looks like this, which creates its own instance of RequestManager. Now this method is on the top level, and it obviously does not extend KoinComponent, therefore I do not have access to the `by lazy()` or the `get()` methods. And since it is a @BindingAdapter method, it has to be top level or inside an Object singleton class, which I have not found a way to inject something into there either.

I would like to change this method:

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun ImageView.bindImage(imageUrl: String?) {
    imageUrl?.let { url ->
        val parsedImageUrl = url.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build()
        Glide.with(this.context)
            .load(parsedImageUrl)
            .apply(
                RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_animation)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image)
            )
            .into(this)
    }
}
```

To look something more like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun ImageView.bindImage(imageUrl: String?) {
    val injectedGlide: RequestManager by lazy()
    imageUrl?.let { url ->
        val parsedImageUrl = url.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build()
        injectedGlide.load(parsedImageUrl)
            .into(this)
    }
}
```

Now my question is, am I approaching this entire situation wrong? Should I not be looking into Injecting my Glide inside the @BindingAdapter method? Is there some other sort of standard I should be following? Does this simply have to do with me using Koin in the wrong way?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to find one way to make it work. I do not know if this is proper use of what I am trying to do, but at least it lets me use my single instance of Glide.

I now have an extra Singleton class

```
object GlideInstance : KoinComponent {
    val glide: RequestManager by inject()
}
```

That injects the RequestManager there. And since it can now be called from a static method, my @BindingAdapter function can simply call it like this

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun ImageView.bindImage(imageUrl: String?) {
    imageUrl?.let { url ->
        val parsedImageUrl = url.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build()
        GlideInstance.glide
            .load(parsedImageUrl)
            .into(this)
    }
}
```

I would still be happy to hear how this could be done better, or why this may not be a good approach.

Comment: To add on top of this, the `bindImage` method could be added inside the object `GlideInstance` in order to access glide directly without needing to call `GlideInstance.glide`. For this to be done however,  the `bindImage` method has to be annotated with `@JvmStatic` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do this:

```
object BindingAdaptersManager : KoinComponent {

    private val imageLoader: ImageLoader by inject(ImageLoader::class.java)

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("imageFromUrl")
    fun bindImageFromUrl(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String?) {
        imageLoader.loadImageUrl(view, imageUrl)
    }
}
```

ImageLoader uses Glide to load a image